# Is there a standard way of calculating these transformations over creation and annihilation operators?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, field-theory, many-body

Suppose we have families $\{a_{x}^{*}\}_{x\in \mathbb{Z}}$ and $\{a_{x}\}_{x\in \mathbb{Z}}$ of fermionic creation and annihilation operators, respectively. By construction, they satisfy canonical anticommutation relations $\{a_{x}^{*},a_{y}^{*}\} = \{a_{x},a_{y}\} = 0$ and $\{a_{x},a_{y}^{*}\} = \delta_{xy}$, where the latter is the usual Kronecker delta. My question is the following. Suppose we have a quadratic form $Q$ of these operators, of the form:
$$iQ = \sum_{x,y}q(x,y)a_{x}^{*}a_{y} + \sum_{x,y}\tilde{q}(x,y)(a_{x}^{*}a_{y}^{*}-a_{x}a_{y}).$$
Is there a standard way of calculating the action of $e^{iQ}$ and $e^{-iQ}$ on creation and annihilation operators? For instance, if I want to compute expressions like:
$$e^{iQ}a_{x}^{*}e^{-iQ} \quad \mbox{and} \quad e^{iQ}a_{x}e^{-iQ},$$
how should I proceed?

*Note:* I am not considering convergence issues when defining $iQ$, but you can restrict the analysis for a finite set $\Lambda \subset \mathbb{Z}$ if you want to be more precise. I don't think this matters in the end here, because I am just interested in learning possible techniques to evaluate the action $e^{iQ}(\cdots) e^{-iQ}$ on operators.

*Note 2:* You can substitute $q(x,y)$ and $\tilde{q}(x,y)$ by numbers if this simplifies the argument.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the case where $Q$ is Hermitian or anti-Hermitian, it can be diagonalized using the Bogolyubov $u-v$ transform:
$$
a_x = \sum_\alpha (u_{x\alpha}c_\alpha + v_{x\alpha}c_\alpha^*), \quad
a_x^* = \sum_\alpha (u_{x\alpha}^*c_\alpha^* + v_{x\alpha}^*c_\alpha), \quad Q = \sum_\alpha \lambda_\alpha c_\alpha^* c_\alpha + C
$$
Knowing $u$, $v$, $\lambda$, it is easy to find the necessary transformation.

Another method is to consider time-dependent operators
$$
a_x(t) = e^{itQ}a_xe^{-itQ},\quad a_x^*(t) = e^{itQ}a_x^*e^{-itQ}
$$
and try to find a solution to the following evolutionary equations
$$
\frac{d}{dt}a_x(t) = i[Q,a_x(t)],\quad \frac{d}{dt}a_x^*(t) = i[Q,a_x^*(t)]\tag{*}
$$
It is natural to look for a solution in the form
$$
a_x(t) = \sum_{x'} (u_{x,x'}(t)a_{x'} + v_{x,x'}(t)a_{x'}^*), \quad
a_x^*(t) = \sum_{x'} (u_{x,x'}^*(t)a_{x'}^* + v_{x,x'}^*(t)a_{x'}).
$$

Two methods are more or less equivalent. I think that if an explicit solution exists, it is formulated as a representation of the matrices $u$ and $v$ in terms of the matrices $q$ and $\tilde{q}$ and can be found in Berezin's book on the second quantization method. I just don't remember if explicit formulas are known for the general $q$ and $\tilde{q}$. In the case where $q(x,y) = f(x-y)$, $\tilde{q}(x,y) = g(x-y)$ and the lattice is finite, it is definitely possible to write relatively simple explicit formulas. This is due to the fact that the solution to system (*) can be found in the form of a composition of plane waves $u_{x,x'}(t) = \sum_k A_k(t)e^{ik(x-x')}$, $v_{x,x'}(t) = \sum_k B_k(t) e^{ik(x-x')}$. I'm not so sure about the infinite lattice case, although it is probably possible to find an answer for this case by treating it as the limit of a large finite lattice.